# firemonkey + xml

Tags: delphi, xml, firemonkey

Проблема в Delphi Berlin.
Мультиплатформенное приложение. Нужно скачать и распарсить XML.
Оказалось, что в правке http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Berlin/en/Using_the_Document_Object_Model нет ничего и примеров тоже не поставляется.

ссылка из справки ведет сюда: https://code.google.com/archive/p/omnixml/
там тоже нет справки

Может есть для кроссплатформенно разработки в Delphi другие библиотеки? Желательно Opensource.

Comment: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/Berlin/en/Code_Examples_by_Functionality#Xml.XMLDoc

Comment: Используйте XML.XMLDoc, XML.XMLIntf. Какая вам разница, что под капотом IXMLDocument? Там может быть MSXML, OmniXML или что угодно другое - это конкретная реализация, задумываться о которой стоит только если производительность дефолтной не устраивает.

Comment: Нет разницы, я просто думал, что XMLDoc - это чисто виндовая штука. Но оказалось, что нет. Скопировал код со старого виндового проекта на мультиплатформенный проект и все завеслось с полпинка.

Answer (score 0):

Думал, что XMLDoc - это чисто виндовая штука. Но оказалось, что нет. Скопировал код со старого виндового проекта на мультиплатформенный проект и все завелось с полпинка.